# Weird Query String behaviour with mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url "/test/index?p=1" and the following apache rewrite rules (Using FuelPHP Framework):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# deal with php5-cgi first
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
    # for normal Apache installations
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
    # for Apache FGCI installations
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

In the index.php, I just do:

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_SERVER);
```

On my local Xamp installation (Windows with mod_php5) I get the following output:

```
// print_r($_GET);
Array
(
    [p] => 1
)
// print_r($_REQUEST);
Array
(
    [p] => 1
)
// print_r($_SERVER);
....
    [QUERY_STRING] => p=1
    [REQUEST_URI] => /test/index?p=1
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
...
```

Thats ok, and that is what I expect. But on my Ubuntu 12.04 server (with FastCGI)  I get:

```
// print_r($_GET);
Array
(
    [/test/index] => 
    [p] => 1
)
// print_r($_REQUEST);
Array
(
    [/test/index] => 
    [p] => 1
)
// print_r($_SERVER);
...
[QUERY_STRING] => /test/index&p=1
[REQUEST_URI] => /test/index?p=1
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
...
```

So the problem is, that $_GET not only returns "p", but also "/test/index".

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: It looks like, on your Ubuntu install, it's using one of the CGI RewriteRules but under "normal Apache installations" conditions - if, on your XAMPP install, you drop one of the cgi rewrites into the 'normal Apache installations' rule, you'll see the same thing happen... the *why of it* has me stumped at the moment though :\

Comment: Yes, you are right, on windows I am using mod_php5 and on linux I am using FastCGI, but how to fix the problem? Removing the QSA doesn't solve it, because then I just have the /test/index and not the p!

Comment: I think this is not FuelPHP related. The `fuelphp` tag is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

This is because on your Ubuntu 12.04 server it is hitting this block:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Reason could be that you don't have `mod_php5` module loaded in Apache.

You're getting 2 elements in `$_GET` due to your use of `QSA` flag. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. So for a URI of `/test/index?p=1` you will get:

1. `p=12` (pre-existing query string)
2. `/test/index` (captured value of `/$1`)

To change this behavior you can use keep your .htaccess as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# deal with php5-cgi first
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, on windows I am using mod_php5 and on linux I am using FastCGI, but how to fix the problem? I have already tried to remove QSA, but then I have just the /test/index and not the p (but I want it in the other way :D).

Comment: I provided a fix in my answer. Use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: Then I get "No input file specified."

Comment: `No input file specified` is probably error from your PHP/CMS framework not from Apache or PHP. What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using FuelPHP, but the message doesn't come from it, since even if I make an "exit;" in the first line of index.php, I get this.

Comment: That message is definitely NOT from rewrite rules that I can tell you.